# Dimmer.h issues with ATmega 128

Tags: arduino-mega, atmega328

I am using a ZCD circuit controlling a TRIAC. Now I am using Dimmer library for this purpose. It works fine with ATMega 328 but whenever I try to upload the code in ATMega 128 using Arduino IDE this error pops up:

```
Arduino: 1.8.4 (Windows 10), Board: "ATmega128, 2.7v, Disabled (default), 16 MHz external"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp: In member function 'void Dimmer::begin(uint8_t, bool)':

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:15:20: error: 'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope

 #define _TCCRxA(X) TCCR ## X ## A

                    ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:16:19: note: in expansion of macro '_TCCRxA'

 #define TCCRxA(X) _TCCRxA(X)

                   ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:157:5: note: in expansion of macro 'TCCRxA'

     TCCRxA(DIMMER_TIMER) = TCCRxA_VALUE;         // Timer config byte A

     ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:17:20: error: 'TCCR2B' was not declared in this scope

 #define _TCCRxB(X) TCCR ## X ## B

                    ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:18:19: note: in expansion of macro '_TCCRxB'

 #define TCCRxB(X) _TCCRxB(X)

                   ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:158:5: note: in expansion of macro 'TCCRxB'

     TCCRxB(DIMMER_TIMER) = TCCRxB_VALUE;         // Timer config byte B

     ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:19:20: error: 'TIMSK2' was not declared in this scope

 #define _TIMSKx(X) TIMSK ## X

                    ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:20:19: note: in expansion of macro '_TIMSKx'

 #define TIMSKx(X) _TIMSKx(X)

                   ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:159:5: note: in expansion of macro 'TIMSKx'

     TIMSKx(DIMMER_TIMER) = 0x02;                 // Timer Compare Match Interrupt Enable

     ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:21:19: error: 'OCR2A' was not declared in this scope

 #define _OCRxA(X) OCR ## X ## A

                   ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:22:18: note: in expansion of macro '_OCRxA'

 #define OCRxA(X) _OCRxA(X)

                  ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Dimmer-master\src\Dimmer.cpp:160:5: note: in expansion of macro 'OCRxA'

     OCRxA(DIMMER_TIMER) = 100 * 60 / acFreq - 1; // Compare value (frequency adjusted)

     ^

exit status 1
Error compiling for board ATmega128.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Any idea what is the issue ?

Comment: ATMega328 and ATMega128 are not completely interchangeable .... the header file has either different register names or the registers do not exist in ATMega128

Comment: what core you use? it is possible, it has only different names. I checked the Dimmer library with MightyCore and for Atmega16/32/164 I get errors because they don't have the timer used by the library. but your errors a different. MightyCore doesn't support 128 (although it is in readme)

Comment: @Juraj I am using Megacore. I need to use 128 because I need a lot of ports.

Comment: @jsotola What you have pointed out looks like the problem.. that is obvious. but is there any work around ?

Comment: `I need a lot of ports` .... for what purpose? ..... it appears that this is an X-Y problem ..... you may or may not have a misguided solution to a lack of I/O pins and you are asking your question in an effort to make the solution work

Answer (score 1):

The Dimmer library doesn't support Atmega128/164/16/32. It has

```
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
#define DIMMER_TIMER 4
#elif defined(__AVR_ATmega32U4__)
#define DIMMER_TIMER 3
#else
#define DIMMER_TIMER 2
#endif
```

For the Atmega128/164/16/32 it will use timer 2. The main errors are:

```
'OCR2A' was not declared in this scope
'TCCR2A' was not declared in this scope
'TCCR2B' was not declared in this scope
'TIMSK2' was not declared in this scope
```

**Possible solution**:

You could try to use timer 3. Only you need to change the timer number in Dimmer.h and in Dimmer.cpp on line 159 change `TIMSKx(DIMMER_TIMER) = 0x02` perhaps to `bitSet(ETIMSK, 3);`. Check the datasheet. I can't test it, I don't have the chip.